# Why does Intellij freeze upon maven pom changes only when the project panel is showing?

Tags: maven, user-interface, intellij-idea, freeze

I know that I should ask this question to the developers of Intelli IDEA and indeed I just did: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138746

However, since IDEA is such a fine program and so many people are happily using it, I was wondering if maybe this is a known issue that could be avoided or resolved.

I searched a lot and there are a number of spurious reports in this direction, but nothing clear.

So these are the steps that allow me to reproduce the problem even after a clean restart of IDEA:

1) Make IDEA use up all the allocated memory (-Xmx750)
- I use Intellij on OSX Yosemite (MacBook Air) and its allocated memory must be used up entirely before this effect shows. 
- Typically I can reach this by opening a couple of projects and changing maven selecting some maven profiles.
- Then the OSX Activity monitor would say the Intellij process uses e.g. 900m real memory.

2) Ensure the project panel is showing and make changes to the pom and then click "import changes". 
- Indexing and import will go at normal speed.
- Then Intellij will stop to indicate any ongoing processes and the UI freezes for about 30 seconds with highest CPU (> 100%) usage.
- Also a little wheel is showing in the top right corner of said project panel.

3) If I hide the project panel, the UI does NOT freeze and is immediately responsive.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually it also happens on my 8GB RAM Linux box :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the project panel is updated on EDT, see and vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117446

Comment: I have voted for your report, but it is 'ancient'. They are not doing much about it?! Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117446 too. Best

Comment: I have accepted your answer, of course we still have to wait for a fix... Curiously the issue is getting traction and is being increasingly voted. So please vote everyone who sees this :)